# Azure storage queue triggered Azure function High Availability

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage, high-availability, azure-storage-queues

We have Azure storage queue triggered Azure function, in order to enable High Availability of the Azure function during **main** storage account outage on **RegionA** where the queue resides, want to enable the Azure function to listen to another queue which belongs to **stand-by** storage account on **RegionB**

In order to achieve the above behavior, thought of modifying queue trigger Azure function to be a event grid triggered Azure function where the event grid to get notified for any new incoming messages on either of the queues of **main** or **stand-by** storage account. Is this solution advisable or any other better way to High availability of queue trigger Azure function?

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, I purpose similar solution recently.

**Storage account for queue**

- I have Azure storage account with replication RAGRS
- Primary Region East US and Secondary Region West US

I want to process Storage queue data with high availability

- Through Azure DevOps pipeline, I have deployed same azure function in 2 regions (East US and West US)
- When East US region Azure function under maintenance or down from Microsoft side, West US function will process my messages.

**Note**: I will keep both functions up and running, so I don't need to detect the failover. Both functions will process data in the round-robin.

Comment: If these functions listen to same queue it leads duplicate processing of queue message. How "functions will process data in the round-robin." is achieved.?

Comment: Multiple function listening to same queue wont result in duplicate process. Azure queue trigger will send a message to only on Azure function.